# logoff7.vbs script error in XP 2 when restart PC

Tags: permission-denied

i have a logoff VB script (it's from http://www.rlmueller.net/Logon7.htm). it's use for limit login user.

In Win 7 the script run just fine but i've get an error in XP SP2 when i restart the PC :

- Script : logoff7.vbs
- line : 63
- char : 9
- Error : Permission denied
- code : 800A0046
- Source : Microsoft VBScrpt runtime error

below is the code :

```
 ' Check if flag file exists for this user.
If (objFSO.FileExists(strFlagFile) = True) Then
    ' Read encoded computer name from the flag file.
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFlagFile, ForReading)
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    objFile.Close
    ' Check encoded computer name.
    If (strLine = strComputerEncoded) Then
        ' Delete the file.
        objFSO.DeleteFile strFlagFile
    End If
    Wscript.Quit
End If
```

script for line: 63 char: 9 is

> objFSO.DeleteFile strFlagFile.

please help me to resolve this problem.

thx before, i'm sorry if my english is not well enough.